# Vim normal mode: Is there a way to explain the changes in behavior with the D (shift + d) command?

Tags: edit

Normally, hitting <kbd>Shift d</kbd> erases everything from the cursor to the end of the line, but sometimes it just deletes one character backwards.

This has happened more than once, but a recent example is that I was experimenting with the `c` operator, because it can be pretty nifty in terms of editing text and automatically going into insert mode.

Something that I pressed in the process triggered a change in behavior with the <kbd>Shift d</kbd> command, and it would be interesting to know what was going on.

I'd give more information if I could.

Comment: Can you run `:map` and see if you have any mappings that start with a capital 'D'?

Comment: The command to run is `:map D`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you miss type `X` for `D`. Both `x` and `d` are close the keyboard.

`X` deletes the previous character.

Comment: Yeah, i always thought it was related to X (that's a great answer, solves this mystery), and it also explains why future instances of D appear to do the same thing after i make that mistake. Whoops!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-)